# Get All Diagonals in a 2 Dimensional Matrix Using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, matrix

Given a 2 dimensional matrix below

```
int[][] m = new int[][] {   new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                            new int[] { 0, 1, 4, 3 },
                            new int[] { 4, 0, 2, 2 },
                            new int[] { 4, 2, 0, 1 }};
```

I would like to use LINQ to get all the diagonals i.e.

`4
3 3
2 4 2
1 1 2 1
0 0 0
4 2
4`

Right now I am using two ugly for loops but I know there has to be a better way.

```
List<List<int>> e = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < m.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = m.Count() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && j == 0))
        {
            e.Add(new List<int> { m[i][j] });
        }

        if (i > 0 && j > 0)
        {
            e[i - j + m.Count() - 1].Add(m[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flattening the matrix and then grouping by the created key:

```
var d = m.SelectMany((row, rowIdx) =>
        row.Select((x, colIdx) => new { Key = rowIdx - colIdx, Value = x }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key, (key, values) => values.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

If diagonals need to be in the logical order, need to also sort the results:

```
var d2 = m.SelectMany((row, rowIdx) => 
         row.Select((x, colIdx) => new { Key = rowIdx - colIdx, Value = x }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(values => values.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. Both statements work quiet well. Sorry can't vote the answer up since my reputation score is below the 15 threshold.

Comment: ToArray() is a rather expensive call. Although this answer is valid to the question asked... I think that the LINQ requirement for this problem is really introducing complexity and performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

### Using LINQ

As far as I can see, this particular problem doesn't really get any performance benefit from using LINQ at all. Maybe you can explain that requirement further, as the performance loss and increased complexity doesn't seem to result in a more "elegant" solution that your current or any other solution that just implements an iterative approach to the problem.

---

### Alternative: Using the Math.Abs Method

I would think that using `Math.Abs()` gives you an efficient loop

```
int length = 4;
for (int i = -length; i <= Math.Abs(length); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    // -4, -3, -2, -1,  0, +1, +2, +3, +4
}
```

This might be a potential solution that uses `Math.Abs()`. It reverses the order when it goes through the center diagonal.

```
int[][] m = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new int[] { 0, 1, 4, 3 },
    new int[] { 4, 0, 2, 2 },
    new int[] { 4, 2, 0, 1 }};

int max = m.Length;
for (int i = -max+1; Math.Abs(i) < max; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= max - Math.Abs(i) - 1; j++)
    {
        int row = i < 0 ? j : i + j;
        int col = i > 0 ? j : (Math.Abs(i) + j);
        Console.Write(m[row][col]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as well and is an improvement on what I started out with but I was looking to avoid loops altogether and use LINQ for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer, after reviewing the requirements I don't see the point of forcing a LINQ statement onto this problem, as the cost of performance and overall bloat that the LINQ statement will transform into at runtime doesn't seem to make the solution more "elegant".